# Can same WCF be accessed in both Jquery and C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have created a WCF service for jQuery by using [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery)
My WCF is currently working in jQuery for PhoneGap app can I use that same WCF service in other application in C#.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can change its Binding/Ednpoint if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the same WCF service for different applications.
Create multiple bindings and multiple endpoints for the same WCF service

**Multiple Bindings**

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConfiguration" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="10.00:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfiguration" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="10.00:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Multiple endpoints** 
-Two endpoints are exposed,one using **webHttpBinding** and the other using **netTcpBinding**

Please note though the difference in the endpoints i.e the use of **behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior"**.The endpoint using webHttpBinding exposes data over JSON.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="behavior" name="WCFCallbackTry.Service1">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8018/Service1.svc" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfiguration" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="WCFCallbackTry.IService" name="HttpEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8004/Service1.svc"  bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfiguration" binding="netTcpBinding"
      contract="WCFCallbackTry.IService" name="NetTcpEndPoint"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8018/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

For exposing WCF using Jquery the below Behavior has to be used as showed in the link that you referenced.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
 <webHttp/>
</behavior>
```

The endpoint using netTCPBinding could be used from a client application using C# whereas the webHttpBinding could be used using JQuery.

Configurations similar to the above could be used with different or same type of bindings, while exposing different endpoints.

Hope this helps